# java regex allow optional space character

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex pattern to match `abcdef`, `abc def`, etc.

The patterns I tried are:

```
[a-z]{3}[\s?][a-z]{3}
[a-z]{3}[\s*][a-z]{3}
[\w]{3}[\s?][\w]{3}
\w{3}\s?\w{3}
```

All of these seem to work for `abc def`, but not for `abcdef`.

{EDIT}

```
AB CD 12 ABC/15 DEF
.*\bAB CD\b\s?(\d+)\s?\bABC\b[/](\d+)\s?\bDEF\b
```

i am trying to extract 12 and 15.

Comment: Seems to be working for me. http://regexr.com?35pkl

Comment: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/ i tried here .. as well through code ..

Comment: It's working there as well.

Comment: Your first 3 are wrong because they include the question mark and asterisk *within* the square brackets, meaning "find a single character which can be a whitespace char or a question mark" -- when inside the [character set] the `?` and `*` **do not** mean "0 or 1" and "0 or more"

Comment: though it works fine in the sites, it doesn't work in the code where i try to extract data using groups, matcher and pattern java methods.

Comment: Is the end game to extract all numbers from the input, no matter where they appear?

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
[\w]{3}\s?[\w]{3}
```

or any of the other combinations. Just remove the `\s` from the brackets or put the quantifier (i.e. `* and ?`) outside of the bracket for the space selector:

```
[\w]{3}[\s]?[\w]{3}
```

Your bottom one *should* work too.

Comment: though it works fine in the sites, it doesn't work in the code where i try to extract data using groups, matcher and pattern java methods.

Answer (score 1):

First one is close

```
[a-z]{3}\s?[a-z]{3}
```

Take the ? Out of the square brackets

java will not be reading it correct. you will need to.escape the \s to \s

Comment: though it works fine in the sites, it doesn't work in the code where i try to extract data using groups, matcher and pattern java methods.

Comment: escape the back slash with another backslash